# ATG - Logging into separate file for each Batch Job

Tags: spring-batch, atg, atg-dynamo

We need to implement separate logs for each BatchJob run. So we are implementing the BJ specific loggers as specified below. But the info.log or debug.log are getting created in default path -  ATG10.1.1\home\logs  but we need to it to be present in ATG10.1.1\home\logs\esk073

```
/Xxxx.BatchJobs/config/com/Xxxx/batch/logging/ESK073Logger.properties

$class=atg.nucleus.logging.RotatingFileLogger
#logFilePath=/logs/esk073
logFilePath={serverHomeDirResource?resourceURI=logs/esk073}
logFileName=eskXXX.log
logListeners=/atg/dynamo/service/logging/LogQueue
scheduler=/atg/dynamo/service/Scheduler
schedule=calendar * . 1 1 0
#logArchivePath=/logs/esk073/archives
logArchivePath={serverHomeDirResource?resourceURI=logs/esk073/archives}
maximumArchiveCount=20
archiveCompressed=true
```

ATG Classes

```
/** Property to hold mPriceCoherenceUpdate. */
private  RotatingFileLogger mLoggingListener;
Create getter and Settter

loggingListener=/com//Xxxx/batch/logging/ESK073Logger
```

IN ATG Classes:

```
if (getLoggingListener().isLoggingDebug()) {
getLoggingListener().logDebug("PricingRepositoryWriter.write() method.STARTS");
}
```